# How to create extension of custom page layout in Magento

Tags: cms

How can i create extension for page layout.
I have no extension for this.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean a layout like 1column, 2column etc or a full page with blocks?

Answer (score 2):

Add new custom layout for few cms pages in one Magento shop. It’s really useful for different static pages of your shop. First create extension with only config file in it: *app/code/local/Metizsoft/CmsPageLayout/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <global>
  <page>
   <layouts>
    <custom_static_page_one>
     <label>Must Login Page</label>
     <template>page/mustloginpage.phtml</template>
    </custom_static_page_one>
   </layouts>
  </page>
 </global>
</config>
```

Then activate it: ***app/etc/modules/Metizsoft_CmsPageLayout.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Metizsoft_CmsPageLayout>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Metizsoft_CmsPageLayout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Clear cache, add your `page/mustloginpage.phtml` template file (or copy some default one for start) to your current theme and you’re done.